# How to save and read the EXACT same data with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The data frame is not the same when saving and then rereading it, despite providing the data type. Why? How do you make it save/read the exact same thing?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

import myproject.io.db as db

old = db.get_dataframe()

old.to_csv(r'mypath\myfile.csv')                    # Save
new = pd.read_csv(r'mypath\myfile.csv', index_col=0)# Read the new save.
assert_frame_equal(old, new)                        # Assertion error, not identical
```

So far, it's understandable: a CSV does not save data types indeed!

So, I manually provided the data types, and then the unexpected happened:

```
new = pd.read_csv(r'mypath\myfile.csv', index_col=0, dtype=old.dtypes.to_dict())
assert_frame_equal(old, new)                        # Assertion error, not identical
```

I am on a legacy codebase with discrepancies, displaying missing values with the built-in and Numpy null values, along with textual nulls:

`None` from built-ins, `NaN` from np.nan(), `"nan"` and `"NULL"`.

---

**Answer (see Matteo Zanoni's answer for the fix):**

Because CSV files do not explicitly save the data type, pandas will have to infer the type of null from every column, including string columns! This leads to very unintuitive behaviours; ***look carefully***:

Along with our nulls, we add string values "placeholder". Each column should, therefore, be considered a string column (object) by Pandas.

OUTPUT BEFORE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    python=[None, "placeholder"], 
    numpy=[np.nan, "placeholder"], 
    textual=["Missing!", "placeholder" ], 
    textual_sql=["NULL", "placeholder"]))

_, _ = display(df), display(df.dtypes)
```

[image: Before]

```
print(
    type(df.python[0]), 
    type(df.numpy[0]), 
    type(df.textual[0]), 
    type(df.textual_sql[0]))
```

[image: Data types before]

OUTPUT AFTER:

```
df.to_csv(r'./data/tmp.csv', index=False)
new_df = pd.read_csv(r'./data/tmp.csv')
_, _ = display(new_df), display(new_df.dtypes)
```

[image: After]

```
print(
    type(df.python[0]), 
    type(df.numpy[0]), 
    type(df.textual[0]), 
    type(df.textual_sql[0]))
```

[image: data type of each value]

Here is the raw CSV file:

[image: CSV file content]

Despite the CSV file not *seemingly* containing any information about the data types, pandas recognized the original type of each value. However, this time, instead of displaying <class 'NoneType'> as `None`, it is now displaying the same data as `NaN`. Regarding the textual "NULL", pandas recognized the value as null, a fair guess, and modified it to a textual "NaN".

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with pickle and most are stuck using .to_csv(). I believe this question and its answer to be valuable. It teaches about the importance of metadata and will prevent a lot of time from being wasted. At least it did for me, thanks Matteo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that saving to a generic text file (like csv) may result in loss of some metadata (like types).

If you want to be sure the dataframe remains identical then I would suggest [pickling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)

```py
old = db.get_account()
old.to_pickle(r'mypath\myfile.pkl')
new = pd.read_pickle(r'mypath\myfile.pkl')
```